# What is the difference between application level DEP and OS level DEP?

Tags: debuggers, exploit

I am trying to teach myself some ROP programming. And I have tried
to do some training exploits from different sites. So, right now, I have this
little application where GS, safeSEH ALSR and DEP are enabled (on application level not on OS). So, when I make an attempt to exploit this application it works pretty well ( http://pastebin.com/TdDR3W0y). It just pops `calc.exe`.

But, on the other side, when I enable OS level DEP, then my exploit generates a segfault and crashes the application.

So, my question is what is the difference between application level DEP and OS level DEP ? Do, I have to make other/different function calls (instead to VirtualProc) when I try to circumvent DEP ?

Comment: Okay i was not shure if this is the right place. Could some OP move the question? Or i have to delete this and create a new one on SO. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the hard-coded values in your code, you are not defeating ASLR at all (0x7c801ad4, 0x0012fbd0, 0x0012fbd0), and perhaps the application does not support it either (0x1003c898, 0x10086d6a), because none of those values should be constant when ASLR is working properly.  The likely reason why you are seeing segfaults is because the 0x7c801ad4 for VirtualAllocEx() probably moved between reboots, as a result of ASLR, but which is visible as a side-effect of enabling DEP and then rebooting.

Comment: I Guess you are right, i have checked again the app in my debugger. And the modules are just DEP/ALSR compatible but it is not enabled at run time. I think a i have to read more about how to defeat ALSR. But anyway thanks